# TS2300: Duplicate Identifier when moved to Angular2 RC2

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript-typings

So, when moving from Angular2 RC1 to RC2 I changed my package.json file to include all the dependencies shown in the updated '[quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)' package.json example -- making my dependencies section of my package.json file look like this:

```
  "dependencies": {       
      "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2",      
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",      
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"   },
```

I then ran `npm install` to get me the new hotness.

This returned myriad errors, but soldering on I eventually got something that seemed like it might work.

When I went to run my `npm start` I was greeted with this:

[image: Tons of typings/browser/ambient/node/ errors]

A whole host of errors relating to typings and TS:2300 duplicate identifiers errors for all sorts of locations.

Answer (score 1):

Looking further at the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) the next step after changing the package.json file and running `npm install` is a warning that the typings folder might not be created correctly.

It instructs users to manually run `npm run typings install`.

After doing this, the error TS2300: Duplicate identifier issues did not go away.

So I deleted the typings folder and re-ran the command to recreate the entire folder from scratch (noting that the new RC2 version seesm to have a different layout than the RC1 version).

After doing this, the lite-server and complication worked and the TS2300 error didn't rear it's head again.

(I'm still having trouble getting RC2 to work... but that's irrelevant to this question)